# Multiple classes in Eclipse but can only run up to 3

Tags: eclipse, class

Just started with Eclipse SDK and am trying to create some simple hello world examples. I have created a total of 4 classes in one Project in Eclipse, but I can only Run the first three. How do you run/debug the classes beyond the first three or is there a limit to the number of classes you can run as a program?

Comment: Your description does not make any sense. Eclipse does not put any such limits.

Comment: Do all four classes have a `public static void main(String[] argv)` method? Only those can be Run.

Comment: That was it-- was missing the main line, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you can only Run classes with a main method.

The method signature needs to be exactly

```
 public static void main(String[] argv)
```